# CVLC with RTSP on 22.04

Tags: 22.04, vlc, rtsp

Just did an LTS upgrade on my security DVR system from 20.04 to 22.04 and got the nasty surprise that VLC in 22.04 dropped support for RTSP. My streamer uses cvlc so this is a bit of a problem.

All the guidance seems to be to just use the snap package, however the snap doesn't include cvlc and I can't simply use the vlc binary as it has issues because it's a headless system and because snap limits where you can write files to. The VLC stable nightlies PPA doesn't appear to be maintained anymore and I'd really prefer not to run the nightlies development versions.

Is the only option really to manually compile VLC to get this functionality back or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: For some reasons VLC seems to degrade, certain features do not work anymore. (e.g recognition of cameras, RTSP and more).
The mpv-player seems to fill the gap, as well as ffmpeg and its companion `ffplay`, which works as RTSP client (receiver) of such stream.

Comment: @kanehekili VLC still supports this functionality, but Debian have removed it from their upstream package. Ubuntu don't make a package of their own and so this functionality is lost here too. It's still available as a compile option for VLC though.